# changing the background color of custom cell

Tags: iphone, uitableview

It looks simple thing but i dont know why i am not able to change the background color of a custom tag on which i am working. Please check my code below for the custom cell.

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {

    if ((self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier])) {

        self.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        self.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
        self.textLabel.text = @"lklklk";
        self.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        self.accessoryView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }

    return self;

}
```

The cell is only displaying the above text with white backgroud

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had to deal with this challenge myself while working on [Spring Cleaning](http://eleganthippo.com/sc)

Here's how I solved the issue:

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
view.opaque = YES;
self.backgroundView = view;
[view release];
```

Comment: thanks jacob for reply but it is not setting the background color for the complete cell. The accessory arrow is still having white background, which is not looking good, i need complete black background

Comment: great jacob, it works, thanks a lot, can u please also help me in increasing the height of the cell from custom cell, i dont want to do it from my viewcontroller

Comment: Ask that in another question and I'll be glad to answer it there. You shouldn't ask more questions in comments. Just ask another one.

Comment: @pankaj, You should also accept the correct answers to your questions by clicking on the hollow checkmark and the up arrow. :)

Answer (score 0):

UITableViewCells have a backgroundView which you need to hide in order to set the backgroundColor:

```
[self.backgroundView setHidden:YES];
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.opaque = NO;
```